# Move an element at bottom left using animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm simply trying to move a `<p>` element at bottom left of the page using *CSS* animation. But I'm not able to animate it properly. The animation starts at original place and abruptly ends at bottom. I want it to be smooth all the way through.

Please help me with the correct code.

Below is my code:

```js
$("#expandable").on('click', function(event) {
  $("#expandable p").addClass("animated rotateOutUpLeft");
});
```

```css
.animated {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes rotateOutUpLeft {
  from {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -90deg);
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
}

.rotateOutUpLeft {
  animation-name: rotateOutUpLeft;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header</h1>

    <div id="expandable">
      <div style="border: grey solid 2px;">
        <h2>clickable div</h2><br>
        <p><strong>text to move</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The animation is not smooth because you're changing the `position` of the element. Does the `p` have to be in `position: static` at the beginning?

Comment: Remove `position: fixed`

Comment: @fabio.sang I haven't really changed the `position` value  at beginning. It is kept default. I don't really have any issue changing the value as long as the layout of my page is intact.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need CSS `@keyframes` to do this:

```js
$("#expandable").on('click', function(event) {
  $("#expandable p").addClass("animate");
});
```

```css
.animate {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -90deg) translateX(-50px);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header</h1>

    <div id="expandable">
      <div style="border: grey solid 2px;">
        <h2>clickable div</h2><br>
        <p><strong>text to move</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution will not place the element at bottom left of page. It is just rotating and placing the element at the left of the original position.

Comment: @GauravRathod The question doesn't ask how to put the element at the bottom, left of the page. The question says that there is already an element at the bottom, left that is being animated incorrectly. If you look at the OPs running code and mine, they both start and end at the same place, but mine does the animation smoothly, which was what the question was asking for.

Comment: Actually I also want the element at bottom left of the page. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @GauravRathod Your question stated: *"I'm simply trying to move a <p> element **at** bottom left of the page using CSS animation."* Since the element in question already is there and given your wording (*at*, not *to*), it was unclear that you wanted to move it to a different location. All you need to do is add a `transform:translate(x, y)` to move the element. My answer still stands as how to do the animation smoothly.

Comment: @CBroe "Backwards"? If by backwards you mean easier, less complicated, better performing with equal results. Yes, backwards. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the position of the element from static (the default value) to fixed, which is not animatable.

One solution is to initally set its position to fixed, and only change the `bottom` property in the animation.

```js
$("#expandable").on('click', function(event) {
  $("#expandable p").addClass("animated rotateOutUpLeft");
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

#expandable p {
  left: 40px;
  bottom: calc(100% - 160px);
  position: absolute;
}


@keyframes rotateOutUpLeft {
  from {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -90deg);
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
}

.rotateOutUpLeft {
  animation-name: rotateOutUpLeft;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header</h1>

    <div id="expandable">
      <div style="border: grey solid 2px;">
        <h2>clickable div</h2><br>
        <p><strong>text to move</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: fabio.sang (sorry the `@` character is not working on my pc) Yes, this is somewhat what I need. But there are multiple elements, placed at different places on the page, which I want to animate. Isn't there any other way to achieve the same result, if fixing the position is not working?

Comment: @GauravRathod the issue is that you can't change `position` and have a smooth animation in CSS only. You could use javascript to set the `top` and `left` properties once the animation begins, though.
Another solution is to position the elements in `absolute`. I updated my answer with `position: absolute`